# Display gallery on bottom after content

Tags: functions, shortcode, gallery

How to execute the gallery shortcode after any other content no matter where the shortcode is in the post HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bulletproof, but should work perfectly fine in most cases:

```
class WPSE_105676_Gallery_First {
    private static $_gallery = '',
                   $_handler;

    public static function gallery( $attr ) {
        self::$_gallery .= is_callable( self::$_handler ) ? call_user_func( self::$_handler, $attr ) : '';
        return '';
    }

    public static function content( $text ) {
        $text .= self::$_gallery;
        self::$_gallery = '';
        return $text;
    }

    public static function startup() {
        if ( ! isset( self::$_handler ) ) {
            if ( empty( $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']['gallery'] ) || ! self::$_handler = $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags']['gallery'] )
                self::$_handler = 'gallery_shortcode';

            add_shortcode( 'gallery', array( __class__, 'gallery' ) );
        }

        add_filter( 'the_content', array( __class__, 'content' ), 1000 );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', array( 'WPSE_105676_Gallery_First', 'startup' ), 100 );
```

In layman's terms, in `startup()` we save the current shortcode handler for `gallery` (so this should also work with plugins & themes that override the default), then replace it with our own `gallery()` method. This is where we "capture" the gallery & return an empty string, so it no longer appears where the shortcode existed.

Out `content()` method is hooked to `the_content` on a low-priority filter to ensure it runs after all shortcode has been parsed, plus any other filters that might add their own content. This appends the captured gallery, resets the property, and returns the post content.

Comment: Thanks for your code and your explanations, but it doesn't work. Gallery stays on top.

Comment: Works for me. Where have you placed the code? And are you referring to the front-end, or in the editor in the admin?

Comment: You are right, sorry. With native gallery, it works. But not with my custom gallery `add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'lilith_gallery' );`

Comment: Is your custom function returning the code or echo'ing it?

Comment: Right again! :) With "echo", it doesn't work. With "return", your code works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Vincent **Always** use `return` with shortcode handlers :)